# What are the official names of the letters "b" and "v"?

Tags: ortografía, letras

The letters **b** and **v** have several possible names in Spanish. Is there an official, language academy-sponsored name for these letters? If not, what are the most common and standard names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas* from the RAE claims that:

- [The letter **b**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=b) is called *la be* and may also be called *be alta* or *be larga* in the Americas.
- [The letter **v**](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=v) is called *la uve* and may also be called *ve*, *ve baja*, *ve corta*, or *ve chica*. The recommended name is *uve* to clearly distinguish the letter from **b**.

As a side note, the RAE also claims that:

> la pronunciación correcta de la letra *v* en español es idéntica a la de la *b*

Which means:

> the correct pronunciation of the letter *v* in Spanish is identical to that of *b*

Therefore, the labiodental pronunciation of *ve* (i.e. how **v** is pronounced in English) is not a valid name for **v** in Spanish.

Comment: Do you have a link or page number for that reference?

Comment: The addresses are http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=b and http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=v. The phrases _The letter b_ and _The letter v_ on my answer are links to these pages. The main page of the _Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas_ is http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/.

Comment: Tee hee: pronounce BBVA and BBUBA out loud using *uve*.  Good on the RAE for clearing up the ambiguity!

Comment: @michaelwolf the /e/ would be unstressed in the first, stressed in the second. It's subtle, but it is possible to distinguish.

Answer (score 8):

Even though this won't answer fully your question, I've found this on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography):

> The letters ⟨b⟩ and ⟨v⟩ were originally simply known as **be** and **ve**. However, there is no longer any distinction between the sounds of these letters—their accepted names are *be* and *uve*;[5][6] in some regions, speakers may instead add something to the names to distinguish them. Some Mexicans and most Peruvians generally say **be grande** / **ve chica** ('big B' / 'little V'); Argentines and Chileans, **be larga** / **ve corta** ('long B' / 'short V'). Some people give examples of words spelt with the letter; e.g., **be de burro** / **ve de vaca** ('b of burro' / 'v of vaca'). Regardless of these regional differences, all Spanish-speaking people recognize **be** as the official name of B.

Comment: Also in Spain is "be de Barcelona, ve de Valencia"

Answer (score 4):

In the list of changes made by RAE in 2010 (see the link below) in the section 2 **"Propuesta de un solo nombre para cada una de las letras del abecedario"** they propose to use a single name for each of the letters. Their recommendation is the following:

- b, B: be
- v, V: uve

Their commentary:

> La recomendación de utilizar un solo nombre para cada letra no implica, en modo alguno, que se consideren incorrectas las variantes denominativas con vigencia en el uso que presentan algunas de ellas, y que a continuación se comentan:
>
> - La letra **v** tiene dos nombres: *uve* y *ve*. El nombre *uve* es el único empleado en España, pero también es conocido y usado en buena parte de América, donde, no obstante, está más extendido el nombre *ve*. Los hispanohablantes que utilizan el nombre *ve* suelen acompañarlo de los adjetivos *corta, chica, chiquita, pequeña* o *baja*, para poder distinguir en la lengua oral el nombre de esta letra del de la letra *b (be)*, que se pronuncia exactamente igual. El hecho de que el nombre *uve* se distinga sin necesidad de añadidos del nombre de la letra *b* justifica su elección como la denominación recomendada para la *v* en todo el ámbito hispánico.
> - La letra **b** se denomina simplemente be entre aquellos hispanohablantes que utilizan el nombre *uve* para la letra *v*. En cambio, quienes llaman *ve* (*corta, chica, chiquita, pequeña* o *baja*) a la *v* utilizan habitualmente para la *b* las denominaciones complejas *"be larga", "be grande"* o *"be alta"*, añadiendo en cada caso el adjetivo opuesto al que emplean para referirse a la *v*.

-- [Principales novedades de la última edición de la *Ortografía de la lengua española* 2010](http://www.rae.es/rae/gestores/gespub000018.nsf/%28voAnexos%29/arch8100821B76809110C12571B80038BA4A/$File/CuestionesparaelFAQdeconsultas.htm#ap0)

Answer (score 2):

In the Rio Grande Valley as well as Mexico, many people have trouble making the distinction in pronouncion so, we say: B de Burro Y V de Vaca, thus effecting the clarification between a donkey and a cow.

Comment: In Mexico years ago I learned to say "ve" for "b" and "eve" for "v".