# "Pali" or "Bali"

Tags: vocabulario

I keep hearing something like "pali" or "bali" in a speech which **might** mean "Ok", "All right" as I understand from the context. I didn't find that word in a dictionary. What can it be?

Comment: Is not Bali is Vale, meaning ok.

Comment: You can find the expression _vale_ (meaning "OK") in the DLE entry for the verb _valer_ [here](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bIEq7WY#BcaKjY7).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is said is "***[vale](https://dle.rae.es/valer#BcaKjY7)***" (literally "it values / it is worth"), a very common interjection indeed meaning "OK / All right".

Note that the letters ***V*** and ***B*** are pronounced the same by most native Spanish speakers and that their pronunciation is closer to an English *B* than to an English *V*, the reason why you misheard that *V*.

See [Historical pronunciation of letters "b" and "v"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/446/historical-pronunciation-of-letters-b-and-v)