# ¿Hay algún acento español en el mundo en el que distingan la "b" de la "v"?

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, betacismo

Me refiero a un acento que tenga todo el mundo de una región, sin contar a gente particular que la distinga por influencia extranjera.

Comment: Hola Damaru y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. ¿Qué quiere decir _acento que **game**_? Probablemente encuentres la respuesta a tu pregunta en [Are there any dialects of modern Spanish which preserve a phonemic distinction between b and v?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19254/1674) y en pedacitos de [Is the v in “vino” pronunciated as a b or v?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16168/1674), ambas respuestas del mimsmo erudito autor. Revísalas y dale a [edit] para añadir cosas a tu pregunta si consideras que hay algún matiz que no queda resuelto allí.

Comment: @fedorqui Errata debido al autocorrector, las otras preguntas han respondido a la mía, sí. Gracias

Comment: Fantástico, procedo pues a marcarla como duplicada. No dudes en volver con más dudas :)