# Can "pasadero" be used to mean a visitor?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, escritura-manuscrita

The word was used to describe someone in a 1930s census, the others were occupations, school and the like, but on looking up the word, one of its meanings is a stepping stone.

[image]

Comment: It looks like there was perhaps a transcription error, and what was meant was "pasajero" (traveler, prob. in this case *transient*).  It's just one letter off.

Comment: I've just seen a topic called "Definition of 'escuela' and 'colegio'" down the side of the page - if it's of any interest here, the hija listed in this image is 2 years old and it looks to me like her "occupation" says "nada, al colegio"

Comment: What's the column heading?

Comment: I've added an image of the heading as I'd to keep going back and forth every couple or few words to type it out.

Comment: @walen - Ah, I see the B now, I had been stuck on that.  Progress!

Answer (score 1):

The column heading for *that* column says:

> Parentesco
>   o razón
>   de convivencia
>   con el
>   cabeza de
>   familia

Which means «relationship or reason why that person is living with that family».

The word itself looks more like «**posadero**» to me, which means «innkeeper». (Notice that the second letter in «p**o**sadero» looks exactly like the 'o' in «Ch**o**fer» and «J**o**rnalero», but different than the 'a' in those same words. So definitely «posadero».) It might make sense for an innkeeper to live in the same house than the family they are hosting.

The column for the profession is the one to the left and it says «jornalero» (day laborer).

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking, but I've replaced the heading of column 6 with that of column 7

Comment: What was (or is) the difference between labourer and day labourer?

Comment: I see what you're saying about the other O's and A's we've been able to see, but people aren't always consistent how they write cursive O and A.  But it's hard to know whether innkeeper or transient (which is an adjective that can be used as a noun, I think) fits better when we can't see the context, the whole page.  Hopefully OP will provide additional images.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the Diccionario de la lengua española and it turns out **[pasadero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S2EV23Y)** is an obsolete way of saying *transient*.

> 6. adj. desus. transitorio

("desus." is short for "desusado" or *no longer used*)

This fits with *jornalero* much better than innkeeper.  So, I would answer your question with a **yes, sort of**.  Perhaps this worker was at this address for a few days working on a project -- for example, preparing the ground for a patio, digging an outhouse, etc.

You were also interested in understanding "jornalero."  I don't know what period and place your census entry is from, but I can say that in Mexico *jornalero* is used for an unskilled laborer, as opposed to someone who's been trained in a trade.  For example, the *jornalero* might dig the trenches to lay the foundation for a house; the *albañil* would mark where to dig and would do the stonemasonry to lay the foundations.  There are plenty of other tasks a *jornalero* could do -- that was just an example.

I'd venture a guess that the daughter works at the school in some capacity, and that the age was misunderstood, because "colegio" doesn't fit with a two-year-old even now, and in previous years, two-year-olds didn't go to school.

Comment: I've added a snippet of another child aged under ten who has the similar extra description before the word colegio. A little above is the entry of the word colegio only for a child over ten years old.

Comment: What I thought said "nada" now looks to be something else, but still a negative, so, probably something like "not at school yet".

Comment: if you want to expand your question, it would be helpful to edit it so that it completely reflects everything you want to know.  Alternatively you could post an auxiliary (separate but related) question. // Supplementary information can provide key clues.  Snippets are quite limited in their helpfulness (for me, at least).  There is no shortage of space for you to add images.  I would find it quite helpful if, in addition to the close-up snippets, you would include a panoramic view of the whole page. // I agree with @walen that ...

Comment: ... the last line of your current Image #2 says, "No ba al Colegio," which means, as he says, "No va al Colegio."  It's an extremely common, minor spelling error, since, as you may know, "ba" and "va" are often pronounced the same. // Just in case you hadn't deciphered the middle line of current Image #2 yet -- it says "difunta," which means "deceased." // Could you also tell us the country and the year?  Might not be bad to also share your motivation -- I'm guessing you're working on some family genealogy....

Comment: I was looking into family history and got this 1930 padron from Provincia de Viscaya, Spain. I could read difunto, but I would never have guessed the squiggle that is the ch of chofer in a million years!  Considering what I know, including some astonishing handwriting I have seen in other documents, pasadero is the correct word.  So my original problem has been resolved.  Thank you.

Comment: The v and b subject seems to be more a Basque way of spelling the sound as the same has occurred with a street name and a surname, where I have seen b and v versions of each but I hadn't considered it could happen with ordinary vocabulary. I expect there's some overlapping with the Spanish and Basque languages.

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/446/9385