# ¿Hay palabras en uso que hayan simplificado el grupo -pt- en -t-?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, historia, ortografía

Hay un famoso soneto de Quevedo cuyas dos últimas estrofas (ver [versión A](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_una_nariz)) dicen así:

> Érase un espolón de una galera,
>   érase una pirámide de Egipto,
>   las doce Tribus de narices era.
>
> Érase un naricísimo infinito,
>   muchísimo nariz, nariz tan fiera
>   que en la cara de Anás fuera delito.

Cito a continuación [un artículo](https://www.delcastellano.com/utilidad-faltas-ortografia/) de lectura recomendada:

> Quizá lo que más nos pueda estar extrañando es la rima D: «Eg**ipto**» no tiene rima consonante con «infin**ito**» ni con «del**ito**».
>
> Realmente esto nos está diciendo que en época de Quevedo [...] **el grupo consonántico *pt* estaba simplificado en *t***, es decir, se decía ⁠—⁠y se podía escribir⁠—⁠ *Egito*, que ahora sí rima con las otras dos.

Esta simplificación ha llegado hasta nuestros días en palabras como *[setiembre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=XdBRd9c)*, aunque según el CORDE la variante *septiembre* se usa el doble, y según Google *septiembre* gana por goleada. También aparecen en el DLE algunos arcaísmos, como *[otubre](https://dle.rae.es/?id=RLRrH5i)* (reducción de *ct* en *t* en este caso) y *[acetar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0OhSctF)* (por *aceptar*).

Así que pregunto: ¿hay alguna palabra que, tras pasar por dicha reducción de *pt* en *t*, haya simplificado su forma escrita y su uso así sea mayoritario con respecto a la versión sin simplificar?

Comment: *pterodáctilo*, por ejemplo? O se tiene que escribir solo con *t*?

Comment: @blonfu no parece que _terodátilo_ sea muy común. :-)

Comment: pensaba en que no se pronunciaba la *p*, veo que buscas que no se escriba tampoco

Comment: @blonfu siento si la redacción de la pregunta ha quedado un poco ambigua, he actualizado la pregunta final para dejar claro que me refería a la forma escrita.

Comment: Según otro artículo de esa misma web parece que ha ocurrido más bien lo contrario como con *Egito*, que en un momento palabras que se habían simplificado volvieron a la forma original: https://www.delcastellano.com/setiembre-otubre/#reconstrucciones-en-el-siglo-de-oro

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios ejemplos de latín:

- aptāre → atar (later learned borrowing *aptar*)
- scriptum → escripto, escrito
- septimus → séptimo, sétimo
- baptismus → baptismo, bautismo
- captivare → captivo, cautivo

E incluso unos que también han perdido la /t/:

- septimana → setmana → semana

---

Related: [Historical pronunciation of letters "b" and "v"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/446/historical-pronunciation-of-letters-b-and-v/25689#25689) (final section, /-p/ → /-b/ → /-β/ → /-w/ (→ ∅))

Comment: Resulta interesante cómo los dos últimos ejemplos introdujeron una _u_: _bautismo, cautivo_, en vez de simplificar el grupo en _t_: _batismo, cativo_.

Comment: @Charlie ese cambio depende de la edad de la palabra, y [su contexto fonológico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/446/historical-pronunciation-of-letters-b-and-v/25689#25689).